# How can I write a function that returns the mathematical operator if two variables are equal to the third variable?

Tags: java, function, if-statement, parameter-passing, return-value

for example

```
public String mathFunction(4,2,6) returns "+",
public String mathFunction(2,2,4) returns "+*", (+ and *)
public String mathFunction(7,1,12) returns "None"
```

/* My Code */

```
public class mathFunction {
    public static void main(String... nums) {
        int num1, num2, num3;
        if (num1 * num2 == num3) { /*returns "*" if true */ 
            String multiply = public static String.valueOf(nums);
            System.out.println(multiply);
        }
        else if (num1 / num2 == num3) { /*returns "/" if true */ 
            String divide = public static String.valueOf(nums);
            System.out.println(divide);
        }
        else if (num1 + num2 == num3) {  /*returns "+" if true */                             
            String add = public static String.valueOf(nums);
            System.out.println(add);
        }
        else if (num1 - num2 == num3) { /*returns "-" if true */
            String subtract = public static String.valueOf(nums);
            System.out.println(subtract);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("None")
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your Problem?

Comment: what is the purpose of `public static` inside a method body?

Comment: This `String multiply = public static String.valueOf(nums);` does not make any sense. If you want to print the `*` symbol, you can `System.out.print('*');`

Comment: Your method accepts a variable called `nums` but you're trying to use variables called `num1`, `num2`, `num3` which have no declared value.

Comment: Also your instructions say you need a **method called `mathFunction`** that returns a string. There's no indication in your code that you've tried to write such a method.

Comment: This looks like a homework question, please see "[How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)" for the requirements for those.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, If you want your function indetify multy operators like `public String mathFunction(2,2,4) returns "+*", (+ and *)`, You should not use `else if`.

Because if one of the `if`s become true, the next `else if`s will not be checked.

In your case, All of conditions must be written as `if` and if any of them become true, the operator of that condition must be added to the `operators` string.

Finally, You must check that if the `operators` is empty, the function returns the `"None"` and otherwise the `operators` will be returned.

```
public String mathFunction(int num1, int num2, int num3){
    String operators = "";
    if(num1 + num2 == num3){
        operators += "+";
    }
    if(num1 - num2 == num3){
        operators += "-";
    }
    if(num1 * num2 == num3){
        operators += "*";
    }
    if(num1 / num2 == num3){
        operators += "/";
    }
    if(operators.equals(""){
        return "None";
    } else{
        return operators;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem here is that you use `else if` repeatedly. This means that one of the expressions is true, the others will never be checked.

I would recommend the use of a StringJoiner (or use just good old String concatenation). The most basic version for it would be something like this

```
  public static void main(String... nums) {
        int num1 = Integer.valueOf(nums[0]);
        int num2 = Integer.valueOf(nums[1]);
        int num3 = Integer.valueOf(nums[2]);

        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
        if (num1 * num2 == num3) { /*returns "*" if true */ 
            output.append("*");
        }
        if (num1 / num2 == num3) { /*returns "/" if true */ 
            output.append("/");
        }
        if (num1 + num2 == num3) {  /*returns "+" if true */                             
            output.append("+");
        }
        if (num1 - num2 == num3) { /*returns "-" if true */
            output.append("-");
        }
        if (output.length() == 0) {
            System.out.println("None");
        } else {
            System.out.println(output.toString());
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like that (Sorry if thats not correct Java Synthax):

```
    public string mathFunction(double num1, double num2, double num3)
    {
        string result = string.Empty;
        if (num1 * num2 == num3)
        {
            result += "*";
        }
        if (num1 / num2 == num3)
        {
            result += "/";
        }
        if (num1 + num2 == num3)
        {
            result += "+";
        }
        if (num1 - num2 == num3)
        {
            result += "-";
        }
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(result)) return "None";

        return result;
    }
```